# MySQL escaping empty / null records

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database. One is `jobs` and the other is `type_of_service` where the columns `case_reference` and `ref_number` are binded which means for each case case_reference the same number appears in ref_number and it is unique and auto increases in a custom way and they  look  like:

```
JOBS
==========

case_reference | customer | vessel
===============|==========|========
    1311/2     |   Dave   |  rg8   
    1311/3     |   Billy  |  fjg32 
    1311/4     |   Alex   |  sh599
```

and :

```
TYPE_OF_SERVICE
===============

ref_number | one | two | three | four 
========================================
   1311/2  |fire |     |       | medical
   1311/3  |     |foam |       |          
   1311/4  |     |foam |engine | medical
```

Now in my web application i would like to show search results in a way like :

```
reference | customer | vessel | type of service
================================================
  1311/2  |  Dave    | rg8    | fire-medical
  1311/3  |  Billy   | fjg32  | foam
  1311/4  |  Alex    | sh599  | foam-engine-medical
```

The method i am getting my results is:

$records = array();

```
// build array of field names=============================================================================
        $fields=array('customer','vessel',
                     'one','two','three','four');

        // initialize empty array for WHERE clauses
        $wheres=array();

        // loop through field names, get POSTed values,
        // and build array of WHERE clauses, excluding false values
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
          // get existing field value from POST, mark missing or empty value as FALSE
          ${$field} = isset($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field])!=''
              ? trim($_POST[$field]) : false;

          // add to array of WHERE clauses only if value is not FALSE
          if (${$field}) { $wheres[]="$field LIKE '%".${$field}."%'"; }

        }
        // build SELECT statement from WHERE clauses
        $sql="SELECT * FROM jobs,services WHERE ref_number = case_reference AND ".
             (!empty($wheres) ? implode(" AND ",$wheres) : '1=1').
             ";";
```

and the method to show them:

```
<tbody>
            <?php 
                foreach($records as $r) {
                    $watson = $r->case_reference;
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo  escape($r->case_reference); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo  escape($r->customer); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo  escape($r->vessel); ?></td>
                        <td><?php for ($i=0; $i <= $found; $i++) {  echo  escape(<?php echo '<pre>'.$records[$i]->one.'-'.$records[$i]->two.'-'.$records[$i]->three.'-'.
                                        $records[$i]->four'</pre>'} ?>); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
        </tbody>
```

But the problem i have is that when i try to do so the following result happens :

```
reference | customer | vessel | type of service
================================================
  1311/2  |  Dave    | rg8    | fire---medical-,
  1311/3  |  Billy   | fjg32  | -foam---
  1311/4  |  Alex    | sh599  | -foam-engine-medical-
```

Is there a way / function to achieve the desired effect without showing extra `"-"` or extra spaces for empty cells in table `type_of_service` ?

Comment: What are your queries?

Comment: show the query you have written

Comment: i updated my initial post with the way i construct my queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it using `CONCAT_WS`

From [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','First name','Second name','Last Name');
    -> 'First name,Second name,Last Name'
mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','First name',NULL,'Last Name');
    -> 'First name,Last Name'
```

So the SQL query will be

```
SELECT a.case_reference AS reference, 
       a.customer AS customer, 
       a.vessel AS vessel, 
       CONCAT_WS('-',b.one,b.two,b.three,b.four) AS types_of_service
FROM JOBS a, 
     TYPES_OF_SERVICE b
WHERE a.case_reference = b.ref_number;
```

As you can see, I have assumed the field to contain a `NULL` if there is no value

```
ref_number | one | two | three | four 
========================================
1311/2     |fire | NULL| NULL  | medical
```

If this is not the case, some extra work is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Litmus.You actually made me realise that my problem is my table wasnt NULLable and thats why i had this problem.If i make all empty records as null my problem is sovled using the CONCAT_WS that you mentioned above!